# Rsync through HTML Button (PHP/Apache)

Tags: php, html, apache, rsync

I have a website with a table that lists all the files in my directory with a checkbox. With the checkboxes, I can select specific folders and then hit an `html` submit button. The button uses `file action` to access a `php` scipt to run `rsync`.

My php script looks like this:

```
<?php
    $folders = $_POST['comp'];
    $N = count($folders);
    echo("You selected the folders: ");
    for ($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
    {
        echo($folders[$i]." ");
        $rsync = "rsync -ruvv -e ssh /cygdrive/c/users/Owner/pictures/".$folders[$i]." blah@192.168.1.10:/var/files/ImageSync";
        shell_exec($rsync);
    }
?>
```

I am getting the Apache error: `'rsync' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

How should I go about fixing this so it can run `Rsync`? I am just learning php, so any explanation would be helpful. I also have ssh key pairs already set up.

Comment: SOLUTION: `$rsync = "c:/cygwin64/bin/rsync.exe -ruvv -e '/usr/bin/ssh.exe -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' /cygdrive/c/users/'owner/pictures/".$folders[$i]." blah@192.168.1.10:/var/files/ImageSync";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you should adjust the PATH environment variable **for a user under which account the Apache runs** in your system so it (the PATH) will contain paths to your `rsync`, `ssh` and so one exe's.

Comment: Thanks! Something like this? `$rsync = "c:/cygwin64/bin/rsync.exe rsync -ruvv -e /usr/bin/ssh.exe /cygdrive/c/users/owner/pictures/".$folders[$i]." blah@192.168.1.10:/var/files/ImageSync";` but I'm getting Host key validation errors

Comment: @AlinaDW No. You need to add yor dir where `rsync` and `ssh` placed to the _system_ variable PATH. I think it will be easier to do for you if you will add this dir to the system-wide PATH variable (can be done using My Computer Properties dialog).

Comment: @AlinaDW The issue with host keys verification relates to the `ssh` auth. procedure. To solve it you may to login using the `ssh` to your remote host by hands one time. In the process of logging in `ssh` could ask you about host key and you could answer "yes" to this question. After this in your home dir a `.ssh` (with dot at the beggining) dir must be created and in this dir a `known_host` file must be created. You need to copy it to a `.ssh` dir which is placed in a home dir of a user under which account the Apache service runs on your system.

Comment: @AlinaDW This was the "right" way. But you may add the `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` option to the `ssh` command-line. This option tells to the `ssh` don't check the host's keys.

Comment: Thanks! That helps explain it. If i try the `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` option, what would the syntax be? For example, is `$rsync = "c:/cygwin64/bin/rsync.exe rsync -ruvv -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -e /usr/bin/ssh.ex /cygdrive/c/users/owner/pictures".$folders[$i]." blah@192.168.1.10:/var/files/ImageSync";` wrong? I still get Host Key Validation Error that way...

Comment: @AlinaDW No. the `-o` option relates to the `ssh` so you need place it to the `ssh`. Something like this: `rsync ... -e 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'`

Comment: Like this right? `$rsync = "c:/cygwin64/bin/rsync.exe rsync -ruvv -e /usr/bin/ssh.exe 'ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' /cygdrive/c/owner/pictures/".$folders[$i]." hefile@192.168.1.10:/var/files/ImageSync";` still getting `Host Key Validation Failed` for some reason? Thanks! I know you've helped me a lot to get this close

Comment: @AlinaDW No. The `-e` option of the `rsync` tells it which shell to use to login to remote host. By default the `rsync` uses the `ssh` so if there is no need to specify some additional params for the `ssh` it is not necessary to specify it for the `rsync`. The second: it's better don't specify an absolute paths in the command line. Taking all the said above the command line will like this: `rsync.exe -ruvv -e 'ssh.exe -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no' <source-dir> <remote-host-dir>`. The third, search please "man rsync" and "man ssh" in the Google.

Comment: @AlinaDW Probably you need to add the `-a` and `-z` options to the `rsync`'s command line (i.e. make `-azuvv` instead `-ruvv` -- the `-a` option implements the `-r`). The `-a` option combines the `-rlptgoD` options, i.e. recursive, copy permissions, time-stamps, groups and owners (the `l` and `D` have meaning for the Linux OS). The `-z` option causes the `rsync` to compress a data while sending so it will do the work faster.

Answer (score 0):

You should find where is rsync in your system and specify it's full path, when you call it.

```
$rsync = "/absolute/path/to/rsync ...";
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried: `$rsync = "/c:/cygwin64/bin/rsync.exe rsync -ruvv -e ssh /cygdrive/c/users/owner/pictures".$folders[$i]." blah@192.168.1.10:/var/files/ImageSync";` but am getting the error `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.` Not very familiar with the syntax here. Do you maybe see it?

Comment: If you're on windows machine, there first slash before `c:` is unnecessary.

Comment: That got the `exec()` to run, thanks! Now I'm getting `rsync: Failed to exec ssh: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: error in IPC code (code 14) at pipe.c(85) [sender=3.1.1]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.1]` Do you think this might be a permissions problem?